# Importing fixed width text file with special characters

Tags: import, ssis

Trying to import these files into a SQL database using SSIS (Visual Studio 2019)
https://rcrainfo.epa.gov/rcrainfo-help/application/publicHelp/index.htm#t=flatfilespecification%2Fffs-manifestmodule.htm

I have setup the flat file connection manager as UTF-8 and it still is padding special characters with one or two spaces - see screenshots. Basically, a slanted apostrophe adds an extra two spaces and messes up the fixed width.[[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFXkX.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n85I4.jpg)

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V05TK.jpg)

I tried nvarchar and varchar datatypes. I have tried all suggestions about trying to convert to DT_WSTR and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but one example is this:
"10650 South De’Anza                             "
It looks like this to the import tool:
"10650 South DeâAnza           "